# How do I remove/decode URL percent encoding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I want to take a `url` and convert it to a more **readable** format. For example I have the following link:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Font
```

I take away the unnecessary parts and am left with `"S%C3%A1ndor_Font"` as a `NSString`. Is there any sort of way to convert this into `"Sándor Font"` (what it actually should be), without having to type out every single combination of special characters and replacing each part of the string?

To demonstrate how I want to use this, I wrote the following sample code:

```
   //request is a NSURLRequest with a url of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Font

    NSRange range = [[request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"/wiki/"];

    NSString *substring = [[[request.URL absoluteString] substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    //ArticleTitleLabel is a UILabel

    self.ArticleTitleLabel.text = substring;
```

In the end I want the label to say `"Sándor Font"` not `"S%C3%A1ndor_Font"`. Thanks!

Comment: Try stringByRemovingPercentEncoding.

Comment: Further to the accepted answer, this is quite a fragile way to arrive at your `S%C3%A1ndor_Font` string in the first place. I suspect `-[NSURL lastPathComponent]` is what you're after

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` on NSString is what you want.

I.e.

```
[substring stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly and I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me! Thanks!

Comment: 'stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated:first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - Use -stringByRemovingPercentEncoding instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Is there a reasonably decent way to accomplish this prior to 10.9? I guess then I just need to test the OS version or catch an exception and call stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Answer (score 44):

For iOS10/Swift 3:

`substring.removingPercentEncoding`

For iOS9/Swift 2.3:

`substring.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`

Comment: Still... Using `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` will not work if you are still supporting older OSs :s

Comment: `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` is actually available since iOS 7.0  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByRemovingPercentEncoding

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3**

```
str.removingPercentEncoding
```

Comment: sweet answer!  :)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2 (Linux support)**

```
let percentString = "hello%20world"
let string = NSString(string: percentString).removingPercentEncoding!
print(string) // hello world
```